# 0xc000000f Issue: Samsung SSD not Showing Under Boot Priority

Tags: boot, samsung-ssd

**This is what the blue screen says:**

*Your PC/Device needs to be repaired*

*A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed*

*Error code 0xc000000f*

*You'll need to use recovery tools. If you don't have any installation media (like a disc or USB device), contact your PC administrator or PC/Device manufacturer.*

For context, I have an HDD and a Samsung 860 EVO SSD which is where my booting is supposed to be from. This SSD was installed over a year ago and everything was working fine and smooth until just now when I turn my PC on to that blue screen message.

**Self-diagnosis:** Going into the bios menu, I found that the Samsung SSD is not detected under the booting priority section, however, I can see it under boot override section, which means that I can manually boot from the SSD, but I cannot set it up so that it automatically boots.

**What's been done so far?** I have made a pen drive a bootable media and through that, I have used cmd for fixmbr, fixboot, scanos, rebuildbcd. Also, manually booted from the SSD to change the boot order from the app, EasyUEFI. No luck.

I have not provided any details of my PC, so if needed, feel free to ask for screenshots/specs, etc.

Thank you for the help!

**Edit 1:**
[SMART1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx0j4.png)
[SMART2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8xQp.png)

Comment: Can you successfully boot via the BIOS boot override?

Comment: Yes. If nothing works out, I can always turn my PC on, go to boot override menu and click on my SSD to boot from there and works just fine. But again I wanted to make it automatic.

Comment: That error may indicate errors on the SSD.  Probably best at this point to recover what you can.

Comment: Since you can boot, please add a screenshot of the SMART variables for the disk to your post. If you don't have such a product, one possibility is [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy) (in Storage section). Also run `chkdsk`.

Comment: See Edit 1 for SMART variables screenshot. Running `chkdsk` found 0 bad sectors.

Comment: The SMART data indicates that your disk is in perfect shape. I suggest to run [Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Startup Repair couldn't fix anything. But noticed something else when booting again: under the override section, the SSD sometimes is detected but sometimes not. If it doesn't detect the SSD, I have to hard shut down and open the BIOS back up and hope that it detects so that I can then boot manually from there.